# How to pass data between fragments and retrieve it in the new fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am currentley launching new activities and passing data liek this:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(c, TastePage.class);
myIntent.putExtra("taste", tempTaste);
c.startActivity(myIntent);
```

and then retrieving the data in the new activity with:

```
 //get data from listview
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String taste = extras.getString("taste");
```

In order to follow android design guidelines better I am implementing a navigation drawer and changing my activities into fragments. I am just a little confused on how to pass data between fragments.

For loading new fragments I am using this code:

```
FragmentManager man=getFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction tran=man.beginTransaction();
                Fragment_two=new BPTopTastes();
                tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_two);//tran.
                tran.addToBackStack(null);
                tran.commit();
```

what can I implement into that code to pass data to the new fragment, and how can I retrieve that data in the new fragment?

Comment: Use a Bundle while calling setArguments on the fragment. SetArguments can only be called before the fragment is attached to the activity.

Comment: Depends on where you keep it. You can keep the data in a Hashtable/Hashmap and keep it in an activity. You can put/get the data from it through calling ((WhateverActivityName)getActivity()).getHash().put("Key", "Value")

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a bundle:

Send data from source fragment

```
Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("user_name", myusername);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

And read from target fragment

```
Bundle args = getArguments();
if (args  != null && args.containsKey("user_name"))
String userName = args.getString("user_name");
```

Comment: you missed the fragment.setArguments line.

Comment: @Elenasys: you could provide the alternative to create static methods in Fragment to avoid having all those method calls in Activity

Comment: Awesome, I think this is exactly what I want. Will try an implement it tomorrow and then I will mark as the correct answer if it works.

Comment: So about to test this but I can not get the fragmentManager from my async task: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21716402/trying-to-launch-a-fragment-from-an-async-task/21716721?noredirect=1#21716721

Answer (score 0):

It is not the best idea but you can also use setters to set some values. You don't have to use Bundle.

```
public class YourFragment extends Fragment{
    private String mUserName;

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        mUserName = userName;
    }
}
```

......

```
FragmentTransaction tran = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
YourFragment fragment = new YourFragment();
fragment.setUserName(myUserName);
tran.add(R.id.main, fragment, "frag");
tran.addToBackStack(null);
tran.commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use Singleton Class to pass information between any component on your android process 
you could access them from your services / activities / fragments ....
for example

```
class GlobalVars{
private GlobalVars global;
private String taste;//generate get/set
public static GlobalVars getinstance(){
if(global==null){global = new GlobalVars();}
return global}}
}
//By Calling
GlobalVars.getinstance()
//you will have a common access to the variables inside the class
```