# trying to launch a fragment from an async task

Tags: android, android-listview, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I have an async task which is called for a fragment and populates a listview. When I try and set the OnClick for the listview I get an error in my code for setting the fragment to load based on the listview item clicked:

```
 FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction tran=man.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment_one = new StylePage2();
                        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("beerIDSent", bID);
                        Fragment_one.setArguments(bundle);
                        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
                        tran.addToBackStack(null);
                        tran.commit();
```

The error shows for the line:

```
FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
```

The error is, can not resolve method getFragmentManager()

I am assuming you can only access that method from within a fragment, so I am a bit lost on how to launch it from something that extends asynctask.

The full code for the async task is below:

```
public class GetStyleStatisticsJSON extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    Context c;
    private ProgressDialog Dialog;


    android.support.v4.app.Fragment Fragment_one;

    public GetStyleStatisticsJSON(Context context)
    {
        c = context;
        Dialog = new ProgressDialog(c);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return readJSONFeed(arg0[0]);
    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Dialog.setMessage("Analyzing Statistics");

        Dialog.setTitle("Loading");
        Dialog.setCancelable(false);
        Dialog.show();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        //decode json here
        try{
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);


            //acces listview
            ListView lv = (ListView) ((Activity) c).findViewById(R.id.yourStyleStatistics);

            //make array list for beer
            final List<StyleInfo> tasteList = new ArrayList<StyleInfo>();



            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                String style = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("style");
                String rate = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("rate");
                String beerID = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");

                int count = i + 1;

                style = count + ". " + style;


                //create object
                StyleInfo tempTaste = new StyleInfo(style, rate, beerID);

                //add to arraylist
                tasteList.add(tempTaste);


                //add items to listview
                StyleInfoAdapter adapter1 = new StyleInfoAdapter(c ,R.layout.brewer_stats_listview, tasteList);
                lv.setAdapter(adapter1);

                //set up clicks
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                                            int arg2, long arg3) {
                        StyleInfo o=(StyleInfo)arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);

                        String bID = o.id;

                        //todo: add onclick for fragment to load
                        FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction tran=man.beginTransaction();
                        Fragment_one = new StylePage2();
                        final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("beerIDSent", bID);
                        Fragment_one.setArguments(bundle);
                        tran.replace(R.id.main, Fragment_one);//tran.
                        tran.addToBackStack(null);
                        tran.commit();



                    }
                });


            }

        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }

        Dialog.dismiss();

    }

    public String readJSONFeed(String URL) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(URL);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream inputStream = entity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringBuilder.append(line);
                }
                inputStream.close();
            } else {
                Log.d("JSON", "Failed to download file");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("readJSONFeed", e.getLocalizedMessage());
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

}
```

***UPDATE***

I tried changing it to this:

```
FragmentManager man = ((Activity) c).getFragmentManager();
```

BUt I am getting this error:

```
Incompatible types.
Required:
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
Found:
android.app.FragmentManager
```

***Update 2***

I just tried this:

```
FragmentManager man= MainDraw.getFragmentManager();
```

and get this error:

```
Non-static method 'getFragmentManager()' cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Comment: Don't know if it will work... But you can try to pass Activity to AsynkTask. And then, when you want to launch your fragment, do that from the activity instance you have in your AsynkTask, just like this: ((CustomActivity) myActivityInstance).methodtolaunchthefragment()... Let me know if this works.

Comment: Other option is to call getFragmentManager() with myActivityInstance. before...

Comment: Android introduced fragments in Android 3.0 (API level 11), so if you are supporting API level < 11, you need to add support library and call getSupportFragmentManager() need to call on context.  link : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html

Comment: Luciano Rodriguez,  I am not fully understanding what your trying to say. This may be a little over my Java Level

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very good practice to always create fragments from the holding activity only, so in this case what you would do is create a callback (interface) in your onclick to your activity that would create the fragment just like you would if you needed to communicate with your activity from your fragment.

doing this will fix your problem because `Activity` has `getFragmentManager()`

**EDIT**

```
OnArticleSelectedListener listener;

public interface OnArticleSelectedListener{
    public void onArticleSelected(/*whatever you want to pass in it*/);
}
```

in your `GetStyleStatisticsJSON` create a method that sets the listener

```
public void setOnArticleSelectedListener(OnArticleSelectedListener listener){
   this.listener = listener;
}
```

then in your onClick just call it

```
listener.onArticleSelected();
```

then declare your asynctask like this

```
GetStyleStatisticsJSON task = new GetStyleStatisticsJSON(getActvity());
task.setOnArticleSelectedListener(new OnArticleSelectedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onArticleSelected(){

    }
});
task.execute(url)
```

Comment: shouldn't I be able to do something within my async task though since I pass the activity to the async task when called with:

new GetStyledataJSON(getActivity()).execute(url);

Comment: sure if you were keeping it as activity but you use `getActivity()` as `context` only which wont do anything for you. if you kept activity you could just do `activity.getFragmentManager()` but like I said that is not good practice with fragment management

Comment: Check out my update, I think I may be close to finding something. But am getting another small error.

Comment: you need `acivity.getSupportFragmentManager()`

Comment: trying to understand how to implement this, can I have a little help with the code? public interface OnArticleSelectedListener {
        //add on click code here
    }

and then call that method from my async task?

Comment: does the interface get placed get placed in MainDraw activity or in my fragment or its own file?

Comment: the actual Interface declaration can be placed where ever you want. You just have to create an instance of it where ever you want to use it

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47370/discussion-between-mike-and-tyczj)

Answer (score 0):

Using

> FragmentManager man= YourActivity.getFragmentManager();

instead of

> FragmentManager man= getFragmentManager();

Comment: just tried this and got another error, check Update 2 in my edited main post above

Comment: Like the Update,you can all use android.app.FragmentManager and android.app.Fragment.If you use android.support.v4.app.Fragment,you can't use tag<fragment>.

Comment: @Mike Like the Update,you can all use android.app.FragmentManager and android.app.Fragment.If you use android.support.v4.app.Fragment,you can't use tag<fragment> and you should extends FragmentActivity then you can use getSupportFragmentManager().